# What does 'ext.' mean in telephone number?

Tags: numbers, abbreviations

People sometimes give me phone number like  (XXX) XXX XXXX  ext. XXX. I was wondering what does this 'ext. XXX' mean?

Comment: *extension*, a line within the phone system at that number.

Comment: Do I dial all the numbers at the same time?

Comment: You only dial the  (XXX) XXX XXXX number. After the call is answered you would say or enter the extension number.

Comment: This should be looked up in a dictionary. [***ext***](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/ext) or [***ext***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/ext) for example.

Comment: @user3169 - I don't see how your [second link](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/ext) would unravel the mystery for a learner who is unfamiliar with this.

Comment: @J.R.  Just check the definitions of the words in the list, and you might find the right definition. Then look for something mentioning a "(tele)phone".

Comment: @user3169 - Given the context, and the five available options, it's not inconceivable that the "ext." would stand for "extra" (as in, "extra digits"). I'm just trying to look at this like a learner might. Moreover, looking up [extension](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/extension) in this same dictionary, it says, "an extra telephone connected to the same line as the main telephone." I'm not sure that that would provide a crystal-clear answer, and I don't think ELL is a bad place to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**ext.** is short for **extension** which is an internal number used within a [**PBX**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=pbx+meaning&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=gNa8Vvf6LLDS8AfrypWYDg) systems.
It is usually an additional **short number** and may or may not be related to the originally dialled number.

The extension number is usually requested and dialled once the caller is **inside** the local PBX system.

Users within the PBX can call each other by using only the extension number.